# Sliding Window for price prediction in python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am implementing sliding window for spot price prediction. Here is the algo:
The historical price of spot instance s is represented as a vector p = [p1, p2, . . . , plp ] ,
p ∈ R^lp , where lp is the length of p , in other words, the length of historical price. For
example, in Fig. 2a, the historical price is displayed when the sampling time is 1 day (24 h)
and the time interval is 1 h, and in this case, the historical price is represented as a vector
( p = [p1, p2, . . . , p24] ) and its length is 24 ( lp = 24).
In this paper, we use sliding window to divide the price data. We use lsw and lpt respectively
to denote the length of sliding window and the length of time window to be predicted.
In order to ensure the accuracy of data division, each sliding length of the sliding window is
set to lpt . So the number of samples we get by sliding the window is:

ns = ⌊lp − lsw/lpt⌋  (1),

In Eq. 1, we get the sample number by rounding down the result, because there is excess
of data, and it is necessary to move the sliding window in reverse. Like in Fig. 2b, the
number of samples is 3 ( ns = 3 ) when the length of sliding window is 12 ( lsw = 12 ) and
the length of time window to be predicted is 4 ( lpt = 4 ). However, in Fig. 2c the number
of samples is 2 ( ns = 2 ) when the length of sliding window is 10 ( lsw = 10 ) and the
length of time window to be predicted is 5 ( lpt = 5 ), and in this case, there is excess
of data. We use D = {D1,D2, . . . ,Dns } to denote the sample set after sliding, where
Di = (xi, yi) is the sample data formed after sliding ns − i + 1 times, and xi ∈ Rlsw is the
sample Di ’s vector, which is the data in sliding window, and yi ∈ Rlpt is sample Di ’s label
vector. Like in Fig. 2b the sample set is D = {(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)} , and in Fig. 2c,
D = {(x1, y1), (x2, y2)}.

xi =[plp−(ns−i+1)lpt−lsw+1, . . . , plp−(ns−i+1)lpt (2) ]

yi =[plp−(ns−i+1)lpt+1, . . . , plp−(ns−i)lpt (3)
[image]

The goal of this paper is to predict the spot instance price, namely, it needs to find a
function f satisfied the following formula:
yi=f(xi),1 ≤ i ≤ ns

Here is my code and data:

```
df=pd.read_csv('spot-prices-2021-05-16.csv',delimiter=';')
df
```

```
Unnamed: 0  AvailabilityZone    InstanceType    ProductDescription  SpotPrice   ymd_hms(Timestamp)
0   1   us-east-1f  r5a.4xlarge Windows 1.0210  2021-05-16 21:14:12
1   2   us-east-1c  r5a.4xlarge Windows 1.0210  2021-05-16 21:14:12
2   3   us-east-1b  r5a.4xlarge Windows 1.0210  2021-05-16 21:14:12
3   4   us-east-1a  r5a.4xlarge Windows 1.0210  2021-05-16 21:14:12
4   5   us-east-1d  p3.8xlarge  Red Hat Enterprise Linux    3.8020  2021-05-16 21:14:07
```

```
df.info()
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 13612 entries, 0 to 13611
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------              --------------  -----  
 0   Unnamed: 0          13612 non-null  int64  
 1   AvailabilityZone    13612 non-null  object 
 2   InstanceType        13612 non-null  object 
 3   ProductDescription  13612 non-null  object 
 4   SpotPrice           13612 non-null  float64
 5   ymd_hms(Timestamp)  13364 non-null  object 
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(4)
memory usage: 638.2+ KB
```

Sliding window

```
from collections import deque

def window(lp,ls,window_size=3,lpt=5):
    window = deque(maxlen=window_size)
    ls= (lp-window_size)/(lpt)
    #for element in ls:
        
     #   if len(window)==window_size:
      #      yield list(window)
       # window.append(element)

#ls = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
ls=df['SpotPrice']
for w in window(ls):
    print(w)
```

Error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a0ca66605811> in <module>()
     12 #ls = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
     13 ls=df['SpotPrice']
---> 14 for w in window(ls):
     15     print(w)

TypeError: window() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ls'
```

Help me to get output. Thanks in advance to stack community.

Answer (score 1):

In the function window you defined four parameters. Two have default values already so you don't need to pass them in as arguments when you call the function - I'm talking about window_size and lpt.

But you **do** need to pass in values for lp and ls. Currently you're only passing one in - the value for ls - which are I think you're actually passing to lp anyway since that's the first argument.

Also, your window function doesn't return anything.

Try this:

```
def window(lp,ls,window_size=3,lpt=5):
    window = deque(maxlen=window_size)
    ls= (lp-window_size)/(lpt)
    for element in ls:
        if len(window)==window_size:
            window.append(element)
    return window

ls=df['SpotPrice']
for w in window(lp=24, ls=ls):
    print(w)
```

I didn't understand from your code what the correct value for lp is with this data so I've just used 24 since that's what was in the example you used.

Comment: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` its giving 'NoneType' error.

Comment: Your window function doesn't return anything so it can't iterate through it later. What do you want it to return?

Comment: It looks like you probably need to uncomment the extra code in your function

Comment: The goal of this paper is to predict the spot instance price, namely, it needs to find a function f satisfied the following formula: yi=f(xi),1 ≤ i ≤ ns

Comment: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable. After edit it say about float.